# C: Top-Down Merge Sort - why infinite recursion?

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, recursion, mergesort

I'm trying to implement merge sort, where the original and auxiliary array are alternated for each recursion. [It's based on a this Java code](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/22mergesort/MergeX.java.html). The description reads as follows ([Link](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/22mergesort/)):

> **Improvements.** We can cut the running time of mergesort substantially with some carefully considered modifications to the implementation.
>
> [...]
>
> - Eliminate the copy to the auxiliary array. It is possible to eliminate the time (but not the space) taken to copy to the auxiliary array used for merging. To do so, we use two invocations of the sort method, one that takes its input from the given array and puts the sorted output in the auxiliary array; the other takes its input from the auxiliary array and puts the sorted output in the given array. With this approach, in a bit of mindbending recursive trickery, we can arrange the recursive calls such that the computation switches the roles of the input array and the auxiliary array at each level.

The following C code is my attempt to alternate the roles of the two arrays:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "mergesort.h"

#define THRESHOLD 20

static size_t size_m = 0;
static size_t elements = 0;
static size_t mod = 0;
static char *a = NULL;
static char *b = NULL;
static char *i = NULL;
static char *j = NULL;
static char *k = NULL;
static char *start = NULL;
static char *middle = NULL;
static char *end = NULL;
static char *e = NULL;
static int (*cmp_m)(const void *, const void *) = NULL;

void sort(char *a, char *b, size_t lmod, size_t rmod) {
    elements = rmod-lmod+1;

    //========== INSERTION SORT ==========
    if(elements <= THRESHOLD) {
        start = b+size_m*lmod;
        end = b+size_m*rmod;

        for(i = start; i <= end; i += size_m) {

            memcpy(e, i, size_m);
            for(j = i-size_m; j >= start && (*cmp_m)((void *)e, (void *)j) < 0; j -= size_m) {
                memcpy(j+size_m, j, size_m);
            }
            memcpy(j+size_m, e, size_m);
        }

        return;
    }

    //========== SPLIT OPERATION ==========//
    size_t mmod = (rmod-lmod)/2;

    sort(b, a, lmod, mmod);
    sort(b, a, mmod+1, rmod);

    //========== CHECK IF CURRENT SUBARRAY IS ALREADY SORTED ==========//
    if((*cmp_m)((void *)(a+size_m*mmod), (void *)(a+size_m*(mmod+1))) <= 0) {
        memcpy(b+lmod, a+lmod, size_m*elements);
        return;
    }

    //========== MERGE OPERATION ==========//
    start = a+size_m*lmod;
    middle = a+size_m*mmod;
    end = a+size_m*rmod;

    i = start;
    j = middle+size_m;

    for(k = start; k <= end; k += size_m) {
        mod = k-a;

        if(i <= middle && (j > end || (*cmp_m)((void *)i, (void *)j) <= 0)) {
            memcpy(b+mod, i, size_m);
            i += size_m;
        } else {
            memcpy(b+mod, j, size_m);
            j += size_m;
        }
    }
}

void mergesort(void *array, size_t num, size_t size, int (*cmp)(const void *a, const void *b)) {
    size_m = size;
    threshold = THRESHOLD;
    a = (char *)array;
    b = (char *)malloc(num*size_m);
    e = (char *)malloc(size_m);
    cmp_m = cmp;

    memcpy(b, a, size_m*num);
    sort(b, a, 0, num-1);

    free(b);
    free(e);
}
```

After profiling with valgrind, it seems my code does infinite recursion (the message was "can't grow stack").

Why does my implementation do infinite recursion?

Comment: Run it through a debugger and it spits out the last line executed. Then try figure out the why and if you can't give us a **clear**, **concise** problem description.

Comment: OT: In C do not cast `malloc()` & Friends. Avoid global variables.

Comment: Stack overflows in *valgrind* don't necessarily mean there's an error in your code. If you have a stack-heavy application, it can well be that *valgrind* is causing the overflow - Reason is, that *valgrind* introduces guard areas between the stack variables and thus may need much more stack space - Start with `ulimit -s unlimited` and retry your *valgrind* run.

Comment: 1) `size_t mmod = (rmod-lmod)/2;` is wrong.

Comment: Why is that wrong?

Comment: It should be `size_t mmod = lmod+(rmod-lmod)/2;`

Comment: That actually worked. I mistakenly thought, `(rmod-lmod)/2` was sufficient...thanks. Can  you post that as an answer, so I can accept it?

Comment: I think that this is  off topic.
It is simply forgot to write the code.

Comment: As a phenomenon,
Infinitely rather than have a recursion,
Because negative unsigned is in large numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, valgrind can't judge the ***element*** decreases or not by recursion.
Try the following code.

```
static void sort(char *a, char *b, size_t n) {
        :
        :
    //========== SPLIT OPERATION ==========//

    size_t  m = n/2;
    sort(b, a, m);
    sort(b + m * size_m, a + m * size_m, n - m);
```